# python list of dictionaries group by and filter issue

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

I have the following list of dictionaries. The list is already sorted. Now I have to group by worker and get his "prskill", but if in case there is not other option he gets None.

For each worker there are max two dictionaries, one with "prskill" None and one with the actual value. if there is only one dictionary his "prskill" is None

my list

```
sorted =    [{worker_nick:  1B  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  B1  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  B2  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Božić  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Božić  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Cimermančič  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Cimermančič  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  CindrićJ  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  CindrićJ  prskill:  razno },
{worker_nick:  CipurićA  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  CipurićA  prskill:  Strežnik },
{worker_nick:  Dančulović  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Dančulović  prskill:  Strežnik },
{worker_nick:  Dragovan  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Dragovan  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Fofana  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Fofana  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  GovednikM  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  GovednikM  prskill:  Strežnik },
{worker_nick:  Hoenigman  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Hoenigman  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Husič  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Huskić  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Huskić  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  JD-Šuligoj  prskill:  JD },
{worker_nick:  JD-Šuligoj  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Jakša  prskill:  Gospodinja },
{worker_nick:  Jakša  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Kastelic  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Kastelic  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Lukinić  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Lukinić  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  MaceleJ  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  MaceleJ  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  MaceleM  prskill:  SestraAmb },
{worker_nick:  MaceleM  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Miketič  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Miketič  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  MikešićG  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  MikešićG  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Muc  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Muc  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Petraš  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Petraš  prskill:  Terapevt },
{worker_nick:  Pezdirc  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Pezdirc  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Prevalšek  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Prevalšek  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Ramušćak  prskill:  SestraAmb },
{worker_nick:  Ramušćak  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  S-T1  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  S-T2  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  S1  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Slanc  prskill:  Terapevt },
{worker_nick:  Slanc  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Sneljer  prskill:  Terapevt },
{worker_nick:  Sneljer  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Stepan  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Stepan  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Sudac  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Sudac  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Tkalac  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Tkalac  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Vidovič  prskill:  SestraOdd },
{worker_nick:  Vidovič  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  VukšiničM  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  VukšiničM  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Vučič  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Vučič  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Čurči  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Čurči  prskill:  Bolničar },
{worker_nick:  Šterk  prskill:  None },
{worker_nick:  Šterk  prskill:  Namestnik direktorja }]
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Below Code:-

```
filteredResult = {}
for sortedDict in sorted:
  if sortedDict['worker_nick'] in filteredResult:
    if None is not sortedDict['prskill']:
      filteredResult[sortedDict['worker_nick']] = sortedDict
  else:
    filteredResult[sortedDict['worker_nick']] = sortedDict

filteredResult.values()
```

O/P of this is unorderd, if you want it in ordered then you have to use orderedDict instead simple dict.